# how to import excel data to 5 specified fields in drupal

Tags: mysql, excel, drupal, drupal-7, field

I have a excel exported file include 5 fields data from a `sql` server database.

So, I want to import this 5 field exported data to 5 specified field on `drupal` (this 5 field is added to drupal user profiles) .

Is feeds module or feed_import module helpful?

I want to do such as following:

```
field 1 (from excel file)  ---->   field_profile1 (on user drupal fields)
field 2 (from excel file)  ---->   field_profile2 (on user drupal fields)
field 3 (from excel file)  ---->   field_profile3 (on user drupal fields)
```

Can you help me for this issue?

How I can import this 5 fields from excel file to special 5 field on drupal user profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a lot [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) on some projects and it works exactly how you need it. You'll probably have to convert Excel (XLS / XLSX) files to CSV files.

1/ Install feeds modules (feeds & feeds_ui).

2/ Add a new importer (structure > Feeds > add importer)

3/ Define the settings :

- Fetcher : File upload
- Parser : CSV parser
- Processor : User processor
- Mapping : The list of column of your CSV file (named is easier) to fields

4/ Go to /import and select the importer you just create.

5/ Validate the settings (separator, header or not, charset) and import the file...

Feeds has a really [nice documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/622696) and you can also find lots of examples and tutorials...

Comment: please see my new question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648718/drupal-feeds-module-import-excel-file-every-excel-column-as-specified-drupal