# Drupal feeds module : import excel file - every excel column as specified drupal field

Tags: excel, drupal, feed, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-feeds

My  installed modules:  feeds , feeds_xls

My excel file is : books.xlxs  (office 2007)

File sheets: my file have 15 sheets (this sheets must be as drupal taxonomy term)

Every sheets involve 6 column (this column and its contents must be as drupal field content)

I created a drupal content type with books name.

I have attached an image to this post. you can see it.

I want to import ecxel file into Drupal content.every row on this tables must import to drupal as a node) content).

[books Excel file image - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o70pH.jpg)

I no have any taxonomy term and extra fields to my content type (book). if I should add fields to drupal content type please say me.

I want to have a book list on my drupal site that users can search on it. every row is a content and every column in file is one field.

Comment: Is your Shift key broken? I'd get that fixed if I were you - imagine not being able to type capital letters!

Comment: ok thank you. sorry

Comment: The edit button is just below the tags line - feel free to use it.